# onclick fetch data and insert into textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, textarea

I would like to fetch all contact rows which are assigned to a group for example 'Mumbai2015'. On compose email page, I would list all groups user owns, and also want that when user clicks a particular group, all assigned contacts should be insert into textarea separated by comma(,).

I would like to get this done over an onclick event with no browser refreshing. Is that possible?

```
<script>
function getFunction(str)
{
var thought = jQuery("textarea#recemail").val();
var getemail = "NULL";
<?php 
$phpvar='"+str+"';
$txtcont = '"+thought+"';                 
$ppwp = $phpvar;
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$usern = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$sql2 = "select GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR ',') allemail from contacts,groups where groups.grpname=contacts.grp and contacts.user='".$usern."' and contacts.level=2 and groups.ID='".$ppwp."';";
$retval2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($retval2);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($retval2);
if($row_cnt > 0) {
$getemail = $row2['allemail'];
echo 'var getemail = "'.$getemail.'";';
}
?>
return getFunction2(getemail);
}
function getFunction2(getemail)
{
var thought = jQuery("textarea#recemail").val();
document.getElementById("recemail").innerHTML= thought+getemail+",";
}</script>
```

Comment: show us sample data expected output by the help of screen shot. also show you effort .

Comment: expose your code man...

Comment: @uzaif edited.. :)

Comment: The query works all fine (checked on mysql), connection is also working..

Comment: ohh js and php mix too much problem with this try to separate it

Comment: how do I go about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your JS and PHP code. 
Put your PHP in a separate php file on your server, and make it return a [JSON object for example](http://nz.php.net/json_encode).

In your Javascript, client-side this time, make use of [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to call your php script, and process the returned JSON in your javascript code, in the $.get callback function.

The techno you will be using by this way is called AJAX `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming).`

Comment: I thought over this and already started working on it.. Thanks..

Comment: I am now getting complete result set in a seperate PHP page, but now how do I get this result and insert into textarea? (and also create a get request in Ajax)

Comment: I put links to documentations, follow them, it's well explained.